# Appium - xcode-select threw an error: command not found

Tags: xcode, macos, rspec, appium

I am attempting to use Appium to test my app on the ios simulator on my mac OS X 10.9.3. I can start the server fine but when I attempt to run my test I receive the following error:

```
info: [debug] Error: xcode-select threw an error
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/helpers.js:499:10
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: xcode-select threw an error)","origValue":"xcode-select threw an error"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 31.780 ms - 176 

error: xcode-select threw error Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: xcode-select: command not found
```

I have checked the bin/sh folder and my xcode-select file does not live there, instead it is located at /usr/bin.

Do I need to configure appium to look in the usr/bin folder for the xcode-select file? If so how do I do this?

Or is there something else I need to do?

Other Information:
I am using zsh and in my .zshrc file I have the following listed:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

(not sure if that information is useful or not)

Also I am using rspec/capybara for my tests. I have added the appium_capybara gem and it installed all other required gems. I have added the following driver information:

```
desired_caps_ios = {
          platform:        "Mac",
          deviceName:      "iPhone Simulator",
          platformName:    "iOS",
          platformVersion: "7.1",
          app:             "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/MacOS/my appname/Payload/appname.app"
      }

      url = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" # or a sauce labs url

      Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
        appium_lib_options = {
            server_url:           url
        }
        all_options = {
            appium_lib:  appium_lib_options,
            caps:        desired_caps_ios
        }
        Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
      end

      Capybara.default_driver = :appium
```

Comment: Appium version? Running from source? If you do `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and then try, what happens?

Comment: Appium version 1.2.2. Tried running the above command, then re-ran the tests and I get the same problem. I have edited my original problem with more details also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this commment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appium-discuss/b3jQ2U4qULs/JHiJgwezkhkJ) (Isaac is one of the contributors), xcode-select **should** be in `/usr/bin` and it clearly is.

I would go to where Appium is installed and run `appium-doctor --ios` to test if it thinks everything is setup correctly. (This makes sure xcode's command line utils are installed correctly)

If it does not, I suggest reinstalling Appium with `appium-version-manager` ([link](https://www.npmjs.org/package/appium-version-manager)) and trying a few different versions of Appium. If it was a bug with Appium, I feel like more people would have run into it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so finally got back to this issue. Seems like my problem was the way I installed Appium. I installed using the appium package. Deleted the package and installed via node and it seems to have fixed the path issue.