# Appium doctor shows error

Tags: ios, appium

When I run Appium doctor it shows:

```
Running iOS Checks
✖ Unknown SW Version Command: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c sw_vers -productVersion
/bin/sh: sw_vers: command not found
Appium-Doctor detected problems. Please fix and rerun Appium-Doctor.
```

Can anyone help let me know what is the wrong here?

Comment: Check your path variable.

Comment: ya I checked it now and modified, now it is showing ✔ Xcode is installed at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
✖ Xcode Command Line Tools are NOT installed: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
/bin/sh: pkgutil: command not found, I installed it by pressing y, after installing also it is displaying the same.

Answer (score 5):

running this solved my problem:

sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the command line tools as marked in your message:

> ✖ Xcode Command Line Tools are NOT installed

From [osxDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/):

1. Launch the Terminal, found in /Applications/Utilities/
2. Type the following command string:

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
3. A software update popup window will appear that asks: “The xcode-select command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?” choose to confirm this by clicking “Install”, then agree to the Terms of Service when requested (feel free to read them thoroughly, we’ll be here)
4. Wait for the Command Line Tools package download to complete, it’ll be about 130MB and installs fairly quickly depending on your connection speed

The installer goes away on its own when complete, and you can then confirm everything is working by trying to use one of the commands that were just installed, like gcc, git, svn, rebase, make, ld, otool, nm, whatever you want from the list below. Assuming the installation went uninterrupted, the command will execute as expected. This also means you can compile and install things from source code directly without having to use a package manager. Enjoy your new unix command line toolkit!

Comment: Ya, I have done the same steps as you specified, but still it is showing the same error. Do we need to set any environment path for command line tools?

Comment: when I execute xcode-select -p, it displays /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer, when I execute command gcc --version it displays Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: @DeepaS did you try to reboot after installation ?

Comment: yes, I have restarted and tried, the same warning is displaying.

Comment: @Deepas whatis your path?

Comment: /bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk::/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk:/platform-tools:/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk:/tools::/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin:

Comment: Now I have xcode 6.1, shall I update xcode and then try to install command line tools?

Comment: @DeepaS then you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952908/appium-xcode-select-threw-an-error-command-not-found)

Comment: Thomas, I have installed command line tools, it is installed in path "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools". when I open xcode preference location the path for command line tools is "/Applications/Xcode.app". And there is no option to change the path. how can I do this?

Comment: @DeepaS in the previous link I gave you, did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26392394/2307070) ?

Comment: Thomas, Yes I read that link and followed the same steps but still I see that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried upgrading to the latest Appium version? Are you installing Appium through terminal? My appium-doctor issues were fixed after I installed Appium through terminal and updated the path variables in .bash profile.  Appium desktop application is different than one installed through command line.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possible area which causing that error:

1. You need to keep all path veriable updated and correct in .bash_profile
2. You must install

   - XCode
   - NodeJS
     properly. You must have all permission to access those.

Answer (score 0):

Install all latest version of following things
JDK (Java Development Kit),
Xcode ,
Command Line tools ,
APPIUM For MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

In my case, xcode command line tool isn't set. Simply go to Xcode>Preferences>Locations>Select desired Xcode version in Command Line Tools. OR from terminal follow Chhagan's answer `xcode-select -s your path`